# MongoDB C# - Hide property from serializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is what my user model looks like:

```
namespace Api.Models
{
    public class User
    {

        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3, ErrorMessage="Username must be between 3 and 20 characters.")]
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Email is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Valid email required.")]
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=8, ErrorMessage="Password must be between 8 and 50 characters.")]
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [BsonRequired]
        public string Salt { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I want to write, and require, all of the properties into the MongoDB Database. What I don't want to do, is expose the **Password** and **Salt** properties when I send this through the request.

Is there any sort of data attribute that I can set that will write it, but not expose it when displayed to any API user?

Comment: What do you mean by "expose it"?  How?

Comment: Say when creating a user via POST, and then sending back the model to the user, I want the Salt and Password to be saved in the mongoDB, but not sent back to the browser/user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is to use view models. Don't pass your domain entities to the views. Design view models that meet the specific requirements of your views. So for example design a view model that doesn't have the Password and Salt properties because that's what this view needs. Then in order to ease the mapping between your domain models and view models you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

If you don't want to follow good practices with view models you still have the possibility to clutter your POST actions with the Bind attribute and decide which properties you want to be included/excluded from model binding. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction([Bind(Exclude="Password,Salt")]User user)
{
    // at this stage the Password and Salt properties will always be null =>
    // they will never be bound from the request even if the user attempts to 
    // forge an HTTP request and include them
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I am very new to C# (I'm a JavaScript guy) but loving it so far. I'll take a look into your suggestion.

Comment: Quick question, this is a Web API asp.net mvc project, will view models work the same way or are they just for hooking into templates?

Comment: You could still use view models and have your API controller actions take them as parameters or return them as results. This way you have total control over what's being serialized as input/output of those actions. Yet inside the actions you would of course map them to your real domain models in order to perform the actual processing.